# Should white go for piece-a-piece or two rook endgame?

Tags: endgame, rook-endgame

As black has the upper hand, should white try to go piece-a-piece (Rooks for Rooks) or try and get the two rook endgame.

```
1r3rk1/p1p2p1p/3p2p1/Rp2p3/3bP1P1/1P1P4/2P3P1/5R1K w - - 0 1
```

Comment: He should probably resign and go for a beer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black has an extra bishop and two extra pawns. Black is *completely and easily winning*, and white can't do anything really constructive.

Black's easiest way to win is to promote a pawn to queen and then checkmate white; that in turn is easiest if white's rooks are exchanged off (take all rooks off the board, and black just plays a5, a4, a3, a2, a1=Q).

So that's what white should avoid -- if there is a choice, *don't exchange the rooks!*

That said, resigning is also a perfectly normal action for white in the given position.

Answer (score 1):

Black has an extra piece and 2 pawns, with an extra pawn being on each side of the board. Black has no glaring pawn weaknesses. If the rooks are off the board, White's only chance, and it is a slim one, will be to lock the pawns up in such a way that Black can make no progress. I don't see how he can do it, especially with those doubled pawns on the g file. For example, Black could play `f6` followed by `h5` or work towards `g5` (to lock the white pawn), `Kg6`, `h5`, then `f5`. White cannot contain the pawns. And that is without taking the Bishop into consideration.

In short, Black wants to get those rooks off the board.